# Implicit spelling mode in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that whenever we use the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) it writes down the corresponding characters?

I know that on Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 I can use the keywords `press` or `spell`, but I would prefer not to have to use these keywords each time I need to spelling something.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.